# Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[Int]'

Tags: swift

Given an array A of non-negative integers, return an array consisting of all the even elements of A, followed by all the odd elements of A.

```
Input: [3,1,2,4]
Output: [2,4,3,1]
The outputs [4,2,3,1], [2,4,1,3], and [4,2,1,3] would also be accepted.
```

I have implemented following, but it throws me an error

> Line 17: cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[Int]'

By the way, are there more elegant solution?

```
class Solution {
    func sortArrayByParity(_ A: [Int]) -> [Int] {
        var oddTemp :[Int] = []
        var evenTemp :[Int] = []

        for a in A
        {
            if a%2 == 0
            {
                evenTemp.append(a)
            }
            else
            {
                oddTemp.append(a)
            }
        }
        // error is thrown in the following
        return evenTemp += oddTemp         
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? Or are you switching from Python?

Comment: I am practicing on Swift by converting python code.

Comment: unrelated: In a playground, you don't have to put things in a class or a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mutate the original array:

```
var a = [3, 1, 2, 4]
a.sort(by: { $0 % 2 < $1 % 2 })
print(a)  //prints [2, 4, 3, 1]
```

If you prefer immutability:

```
let a = [3, 1, 2, 4]
let result: [Int] = a.sorted(by: { $0 % 2 < $1 % 2})
print(result)  //prints [2, 4, 3, 1]
```

---

Other solution:

```
let a = [3,1,2,4]

let result: [Int] = a.reduce(into: []) { accumulator, element in
    let newIndex = element % 2 == 0 ? accumulator.startIndex : accumulator.endIndex
    accumulator.insert(element, at: newIndex)
}
print(result)
```

prints `[4, 2, 3, 1]`

Comment: Is there a way of handling in the array itself, rather than creating additional array?

Answer (score 2):

```
return evenTemp + oddTemp
```

does what you want

Mutable arrays can be sorted in-place, e.g. for your example you could do

```
var a = [0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8,9,10,10,11,11,11,11,12]
a.sort { $1 % 2 > $0 % 2 }
print(a) // [0, 2, 4, 6, 6, 8, 10, 10, 12, 3, 1, 5, 7, 7, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+=` operator mutates the left hand side operand and its return value is `Void`. You need to separate the concanation of the arrays and the return statement into separate lines.

```
evenTemp += oddTemp
return evenTemp
```

Comment: Is there an elegant solution for the given problem, rather than using extra memory space? Is there a way to make it in place?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
evenTemp += oddTemp
```

doesn't return anything

```
evenTemp += oddTemp 
return evenTemp
```

Comment: Is there more elegant solution for the given problem, rather than using extra memory space? Is there a way to make it in place?